# Kubeflow: Image Pull --> no space left on device

Tags: kubernetes, ksonnet, kubeflow

Is there any way to clean all cached docker images etc from a kubernetes setup that could free up space on the master nodes?
I try to install a deployment but the kubernetes prompts “no space left on device” while image pulling.

I am kind of surprised that a 80GB disk is not enough for one simple deployment because the cluster is now completely emptied.

Does anyone has an idea on how to wipe all unused docker image etc out?

Thanks a lot!

```
Successfully pulled image "tensorflow/serving:1.11.1"
  Warning  Failed            4m30s                  kubelet, 192.168.10.37  Failed to pull image "gcr.io/kubeflow-images-public/tf-model-server-http-proxy:v20180606-9dfda4f2": rpc error: code = Unknown desc = failed to register layer: Error processing tar file(exit status 1): write /usr/lib/python3.5/idlelib/__pycache__/CodeContext.cpython-35.pyc: no space left on device
  Warning  Failed            4m27s (x3 over 4m29s)  kubelet, 192.168.10.37  Error: ImagePullBackOff
```

Comment: I'm not sure your cluster is empty. Seems like one of yours cluster nodes is empty.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can run `docker image prune` to clean up unused images or `docker system prune` 
to cleanup all docker unused resources.

Also you can configure [Garbage Collection feature](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/cluster-administration/kubelet-garbage-collection/) of Kubernetes